# Where can I find a table which shows the LaTeX commands for each Unicode Character?

Tags: unicode, unicode-math

Where can I find a table which shows the LaTeX commands for each Unicode Character if such a command exists?

For example the LaTeX command for `∈` is `\in`

Comment: you could use https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?%E2%88%88  for example, or see `texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex`

Answer (score 2):

The list of math-mode symbols is [“Symbols Defined by Unicode-Math.”](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf)

Many of the symbols listed under the Body Text section of [“The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List”](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) will map to Unicode if `fontspec` is loaded.  In particular, those listed under LaTeX and `textcomp` are now enabled by the LaTeX kernel.  Others require an additional package, such as `textalpha` for Greek or `tipauni` for the International Phonetic Alphabet.

In text mode, most Unicode symbols can be entered into the UTF-8 source.  LuaTeX and XeTeX should just work, if you select a font that supports all the characters you use.  PDFLaTeX only supports precomposed characters, not combining accents, and generally requires you to load [an 8-bit font encoding that contains the character.](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf)

You can define any missing Unicode symbol yourself, with the `newunicodechar` package.

Finally, you can also request a given Unicode codepoint with `^^^^12ab`, `\char"12AB` or `\symbol{"12AB}`.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a table, but this is a community wiki and needs to be edited to be complete.

| LaTeX | Unicode Escape Sequence | Human Readable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `\alpha` | `\u03B1` | α |
| `A` | `\u0391` | Α |
| `\approx` | `\u2248` | ≈ |
| `\ast` | `\u2217` | ∗ |
| `\alpha` | `\03B1` | α |
| `\beta` | `\u3b2` | β |
| `\bigcap` | `\u22c2` | ⋂ |
| `\circ` | `\u2218` | ∘ |
| `\cdot` | `\u22c5` | ⋅ |
| `\cdots` | `\u22ef` | ⋯ |
| `\???` | `\u21ab` | ↫ |
| `\???` | `\u21ac` | ↬ |
| `\???` | `\u21b6` | ↶ |
| `\???` | `\u21b7` | ↷ |
| `\???` | `\u21ba` | ↺ |
| `\cwopencirclearrow` | `\u21bb` | ↻ |

Rows are sorted based on the leftmost letter in the LaTeX command if case (lower or upper) did not matter and all backlashes are ignored.

Comment: a completed table woud be too large for this site

Comment: also U+03B1 is a text upright alpha α but `\alpha` is  math italic alpha U+1D6FC 

Comment: you have a latin A (U+0041) marked as U+0391 which is Alpha, Α